# Keyboard lights turn off on laptop poweroff

Tags: keyboard, shutdown, laptop, backlight

I have *Xiaomi RedmiBook Pro 14 2021* with Ubuntu 23.10 on it recently installed as only system.

The laptop has keyboard backlight, which can be enabled/disabled by pressing *Fn+F10*, or with just *F10*. The combination depends on function keys mode, which also can be toggled with *Fn+Escape*.

The problem is if keyboard light is enabled and I shutdown laptop and power it up again after some time, lights will be deactivated. I have to turn the backlight again and also function keys mode appears to be reset.

This doesn't happen if laptop is put in sleep mode, but, of course, I can't keep my laptop powered on forever.

Is there a fix/workaround for this issue?